# Chrome JavaScript console is null after submitting the page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

This was unexpected. I use Chrome as my primary development browser and make generous use of "console.log" (way better than alerts!)

Anyway, I have a page inside an IFrame (for uploading images). That page includes scripts that often write out to the console window (console.log) for tracking purposes. The first time the parent page submits the embedded page via script, everything goes smoothly. If I, however, then attempt to submit the page a second time I get the error ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of null
```

All of a sudden it seems that the console is no longer available. If I replace it with an alert the alert box appears as expected, but the page no longer submits either.

Has anybody experienced anything like this before?

Comment: I really hope no one put `console = null` in a different script called by that `iframe`:)

Comment: Nah ... this is a one person project. No other cooks in the kitchen. The form.submit() is not working after the first submission either.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or provide a link or some code so others can reproduce?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "parent page submits the embedded page via script" or "submit the page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank folks for their responses. I did not include any code in the OP because it is an extensive script and parsing out an "example" of what I was attempting to do so that it wasn't too tedious to go through would likely strip out any relevancy.

I am posting, however to say that I did discover the problem.

I have PageA which contains an IFrame which is in turn loaded with PageB.

```
<html>
<head><title>PageA</title></head>
<body>

    <IFrame src="PageB" name="frame1" id="frame1"></IFrame>    

</body>
</html>
```

PageB contains a function that needs to be called from PageA when a button is clicked.

```
<!-- PageB -->
    <html>
    <head><title>PageB</title></head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" >

    </form>
    <script>

        var SubmitForm = function(){
            var $form = $("form[id$='form1']");
            $form[0].submit(); // this was not firing 
            console.log("some log output"); // this was throwing an error
        };

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- PageA -->
    <html>
    <head><title>PageA</title></head>
    <body>

    <IFrame src="PageB" name="frame1" id="frame1"></IFrame>
    <button onclick="submitIFrameForm()">Submit</button>

    <script>
        var frameWindow    = frames["frame1"];
        var frameForm      = frameWindow.SubmitForm; 

        function submitIFrameForm(){
             frameForm();
        };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

THE PROBLEM

When PageA ***first*** loads, the IFrame is loaded with PageB and the script in PageA makes it's reference (frameForm) to the "SubmItForm()" function on PageB. When I click on the submit form button in PageA, PageB is submitted back to the server. No problem ...

However when PageB is submited it is UNLOADED from the window. So when I click on the 
submit button in PageA a second time, although PageB may reload it is a different instance of the page. Therefore all the variables which reference the original PageB are now pointing to nothing ... hence the window that console was referencing no longer exists, so the "log" method cannot run.

THE FIX

Instead of creating a global reference to the contents of the IFrame, we must re-establish this reference to the function each time the button is clicked. (Since the IFrame is a member of PageA we do not need to re-establish the IFrame reference).

```
<!-- PageA -->
    <html>
    <head><title>PageA</title></head>
    <body>

    <IFrame src="PageB" name="frame1" id="frame1"></IFrame>
    <button onclick="submitIFrameForm()">Submit</button>

    <script>
        var frameWindow    = frames["frame1"];

        function submitIFrameForm(){
             frameWindow.SubmitForm(); // move the reference to the click event handler
        };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope that this made sense and that it helps someone out there. I get caught up on this kind of stuff constantly.